# .htaccess without slash at the end of uri RewriteRule

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Can I use my uri without a slash at the end of uri?

```
http://host/product
http://host/product/
```

My .htaccess allow me to use the latter uri with / at the end. but not the former one. which give me internal server error.

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course you can use optional slash at end. **Just make trailing slash optional in your regex**, something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^product/?$ /product.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you would want to include a `?` after the slash in your RegEx. The question mark makes the preceding character optional.

More information: http://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^product/?$ /product.php [NC]
```